# For basis of a span, if the order of vectors in a span matters.

Tags: linear-algebra

To find a basis for span A = {(1,-1,1), (1,2,-3), (1,5,-7), (3,6,-9)}, I can use row reduction to get its RREF, which is \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0& 1 &2 &3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
Because column 1 & 2 have leading entries, basis A' = {(1,-1,1), (1,2,-3)}.

As we notice, for example, (1,5,-7) can be written as linear combinations of the others, i.e. (1,5,-7)= -1 *(1,-1,1) + 2 *(1,2,-3).
However, (1,-1, 1) = 2 *(1,2,-3) - (1,5,-7). They are all scalar multiples of each other.

If I swap the columns 2 & 3 when reducing, I will get another RREF.
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 3\\ -1& 5 &2 &6 \\ 1 & -7 & 3 & 9 \end{bmatrix}
➡️
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1/2 & 0\\ 0& 1 &1/2 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
Then the basis is {(1,-1,1), (1,5,-7), (3,6,-9)}.

So, here are my questions:

1. is the order of vectors matters in a span? Or is it just matters when looking for its basis?
2. Is finding the basis through the reduction (RREF) without swaping the columns is the only way to get the correct answer?

Thank you.

Comment: For 1:The order of a basis does not matter in terms of the space it spans. It matters, for example, when you want to write the matrix representation of a linear operator with respect to a basis. For 2: You can use any method you want as long as the result is linearly independent and spans the original space. The Gram Schmidt process is an example of another technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you swap columns, you still have to get a basis of the *same* space. And two bases of a space all have the same number of elements. The origin of your error lies in the fact that you have lost a minus sign; your new matrix (after swapping) should in fact be$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ -1 & 5 & 2 & 6 \\ 1 & -7 & \color{red}-3 & -9\end{bmatrix}.$$Its RREF is$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$So, $\{(1,-1,1),(1,5,-7)\}$ is indeed another basis of the same space.